# How do I get a value from a json list using an index in python?

Tags: python, json

How can I print 'abcd' here?

```py
import json

my_dict = {
    "test": "hello world",
    'my_list': [{
        'a_value': "abcd",
        'another_value': 'asdf'
    }]
}

stuff = json.dumps(my_dict)
stuff = json.loads(stuff)

e = stuff[my_list][1] # An attempt
print(e) # IndexError: list index out of range
```

I want to specifically use the index (1, not 'a_value').

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range` ... well `1` is out of range. Indices start with `0` in python. Try that.

Comment: @Drey "{'a_value': 'abcd', 'another_value': 'asdf'}" (I added the double quotes myself, in case there was some confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your attempt:

1. my_list is a key in the json object, it works similar to a dict. Therefore, you must refer to it as a key in the object and enclose it in ''.
2. 'my_list' has the value of a list, therefore the first element of the list shall be accessed, and only then can you access the key 'a_value'.

In dictionary or json objects, you cannot refer to the keys via an index. Therefore, you cannnot use '1' to refer to 'a_value'. Your other option could be to create a list of the values of the object and then use the index. This can be done as:

```
import json

my_dict = {
    "test": "hello world",
    'my_list': [{
        'a_value': "abcd",
        'another_value': 'asdf'
    }]
}

stuff = json.dumps(my_dict)
stuff = json.loads(stuff)
e = list(list(stuff.values())[1][0].values())[0]
print(e)
```

The output of the above statement will be:

```
abcd
```

Or, as suggested by @Dr. Strange Codes, you could do something like this although I am guessing this is not what you are looking for:

```
e = stuff['my_list'][0]['a_value']
```

The output will be:

```
abcd
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```py
import json

my_dict = {
    "test": "hello world",
    'my_list': [{
        'a_value': "abcd",
        'another_value': 'asdf'
    }]
}

stuff = json.dumps(my_dict)
stuff = json.loads(stuff)

e = my_dict['my_list'][0]['a_value']
print(e)
```

It will work!

Comment: I should have been more clear. I want to be able to get the value of 'a_value' without knowing what the key is, but knowing what the index is.

Comment: oK I will try to get that answer. I thought you told to get value of `a_value` by key.